# Typing function parameters so that the check for the second param depends on that for the first param

Tags: typescript

I was trying to type the parameters of a function so that the compiler can perform checks on both correctly. To demonstrate, say I have the type `Item` and a function `f` that needs to be typed:

```
type Item = {
  Book: { price: number };
  Box: { weight: number };
}

const f = (param1, param2): void => { ... }
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
// correct: both name and related attributes are right
f('Book', { price: 20 })
f('Box', { weight: 10 })
// error: 'Chair' is not a 'Book' or 'Box'
f('Chair', { price: 20 })
// error: 'Book' should be provided with a price
f('Book', { weight: 20 })
f('Book', { foo: 20 })
```

I tried to type `f` as follows:

```
const f = (param1: keyof Item, param2: Item[keyof Item]): void => { ... }
```

Which mostly worked, except that

```
f('Box', { price: 200 })
```

did not raise a compiler error.

How should I go about linking the two parameters as described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way you want to go around this is by having `param2` change based on `param1`. Right now what you are saying is `param1` is some key of Item, and `param2` is some value of item that matches **any key**, NOT specifically the key param1.

Instead what you want is `param2` to be the `typeof Item[param2]`. I would do this with generics.

```
type Item = {
    Book: {price: number};
    Box: {weight: number;}
};

const f = <K extends keyof Item, E extends Item[K]>(param1: K, param2: E): void => {}

f('Box', {price: 5})
```

This throws the following error:

```
Argument of type '{ price: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ weight: number; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'price' does not exist in type '{ weight: number; }'.
```

But this does not:

```
f('Box', {weight: 5})
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want two type parameters here?  Why not just have `K` and make `param2: Item[K]` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m35Ayw)?  Also, when you say "the `typeof Item[param2]`" the `typeof` doesn't make sense in that position and presumably you mean `param1`, like `Item[typeof param1]` instead.

Comment: I tried this but it threw another error I don't understand.

Comment: [I don't see a problem](https://tsplay.dev/wX7RQW); can you demonstrate?

Comment: This worked! And the single param version worked as well, as jcalz suggested: ```const f = <T extends keyof Item>(p1: T, p2: Item[T]): void => {};```.

Comment: Ahh I see what I did wrong. You typed `p2: Item[T]` I typed `p2: typeof Item[T]`. Not sure why it doesn't work, but it doesn't!